# Python: When a SyntaxError isn't a syntax error?

Tags: python, error-handling, syntax-error, runtime-error

I've handed over a working Python program to a client. On his machine, it falls over immediately on start-up with:

```
  File "program.py", line 22

    self.wb = openWorkBook(“Workbook.xlsx")

                           ^SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

There's no syntax error here of course, nor is there one in the line preceding it:

```
class Recorded(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        try: 
            self.wb = openWorkBook("Workbook.xlsx")
```

The client unfortunately cannot provide any more details than the error, and logging on to his machine to try reproduce the issues is not an option.

**Given this, where/how should I try to isolate the problem?**

The following context may or may not relevant:

- My Python: 2.7.10
- Client's Python: 2.7.6
- My OS: OS X Yosemite
- Client's OS: OS X (version unknown)

Program is a straightforward IDE-recorded selenium (Webdriver & unittest) test. The line in question above is attempting to open a spreadsheet. `openWorkBook` is a function that just calls `openpyxl.load_workbook()`

Many thanks.

Comment: Notice the quote in the first code.

Comment: And the award for the fastest response and the sharpest eye goes Master Chaudhary. Many thanks.